# Does the spin have to be of opposite sign for fermions to form cooper pairs in bcs theory?

Tags: quantum-spin, superconductivity

I recently started exploring superconductivity and here's what I've understood wrt to bcs theory of superconductivity:
Two electrons can have a close association as there is low agitation of the lattice below the critical temperature. Two fermions together can act as a boson thus having an integral spin of 0 or 1 instead of + or - half so there's no need to worry about pauli's exclusion principle and all that. So does the spin of the electrons acting as a single cooper pair have to be opposite? If so, why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While $^3He$ is superfluid, rather than superconductive, Cooper pairs in $^3He$ have two fermion atoms/quasiparticles with the same spin.

> While $^4He$ is a boson, $^3He$ with three rather than four nucleons
> is a fermion, and superfluid $^3He$ is formed by condensation of
> Cooper pairs of $^3He$ atoms (or more precisely of “quasiparticles” of
> atoms each with a surrounding cloud of other atoms) that have internal
> degrees of freedom. This is because the two partners form a
> spin-triplet in a relative orbital $p$-state. https://www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2018/06/advanced-physicsprize2003-1.pdf

I don't know if a similar situation is possible in superconductivity.

EDIT (Feb 12, 2023): Looks like spin-triplet superconductivity is also possible ([Science, 16 Aug 2019, Vol 365, Issue 6454, pp. 684-687, DOI: 10.1126/science.aav864](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.aav8645)5)